# Neural network with varied input and output sizes

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Is there  any way to design a neural network where if I train it on x (input) and y (output) dataset arrays of length n each, then it can even predict an output if the input given is of length m with an expected output of length m as well? Such that m ≠ n.

My current set up is where I train a MLP regressor from Sci kit learn and using it predict arrays when given input x of length n, same as the training set. However, using the same predictor I would like to be able to predict arrays when the input is of a longer or shorter length than the training set. If there is a way to implement this any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

That's a classic issue in text application (NLP), you should look in that direction to make research.
For example: 
-you can use padding: choose a length N>n,m. Then add zeros at the end of each trainset instances until they are of size N. During inference you can add 0 to instances until they are of size N, this way any input of size [0,N] is covered. 
-you can use LSTM (reccurent newtork) that will work on any input length. 
...

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thomas could you elaborate what can I do in the case where I want to use a larger array than the training input. I believe your method will work for me when I have a smaller prediction input array.